# DOM boxShadow and opacity like css rgba

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am working with the DOM, I have a box shadow all is great but i want the shadow to have rgba opacity like i could have in CSS.

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 20px 30px black";

box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Comment: Please make an attempt at figuring these kinds of things out yourself before asking. Copying the value from CSS into the JavaScript would be the first, most obvious thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use rgba in box shadow example:

html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

css:

```
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

javascript:

```
let box = document.querySelector(".box")

// x offset, y offset, blur radius, spread radius, color
box.style.boxShadow = "0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)"
```